# Protocol error when mounting shared folder

Tags: mount, vmware, shared-folders

The problem: When attempting to access a shared folder between Ubuntu and Windows I got an Errno::EPROTO error.

I am posting this in order to help others who might be as confused as I was.

My environment: Ubuntu 16.04, VMWare Workstation 9.0, Rails 4.2.6

Before cloning a snapshot I was happily accessing a shared folder.  After cloning, I lost access with the EPROTO error.

I was working with SSL, etc., and was completely confused why I lost access.

Answer (score 2):

Answered by [OP](https://askubuntu.com/users/641550/ralphshnelvar) in [question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/871135/1):

> The answer (after a few hours of cursing) was simple:
>
> [image: Virtual Machine Settings Options - VMWare]
>
> Apparently, cloning a VMWare snapshot in my environment does not also copy all the VM settings.  Setting the Shared Folders option to what the source VM settings are solved the problem.